# networkx shallow copy and nodes update

Tags: python, networkx

I've made a shallow copy of a graph successfully when I try to update an edge, the update is seen on both sides of the copy:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(1,2,l=['a','b','c'])
>>> H = nx.Graph(G) # shallow copy
>>> H[1][2]['l']
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> H[1][2]['l'].append('d')
>>> H[1][2]['l']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> G[1][2]['l']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

However, when I try to update a node attribute, I don't undertand why it seems to duplicated :

```
>>> H.nodes[1]
{}
>>> H.nodes[1]["a"] = "b"
>>> H.nodes[1]
{'a': 'b'}
>>> G.nodes[1]
{}
```

According to the documentation here:
(https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.copy.html#networkx.DiGraph.copy)

The shallow copy should produce a sort of pointer to the source data (if I understood properly)... So could someone explain me what's going on and maybe, how to create shallow copies on nodes ?

Thank you